# Search button not responding

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I created a search button to query my MS Access database and display the results but whenever I type in the ID and click search button it does nothing.

Everything else is working, it copies data from the VB form and stores it in the MS Access database but the search button does not query the database and retrieve the data.

Below is my code for the search button:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim found As Boolean

    Try
        cm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = "SELECT* FROM tblInfo WHERE (ID = @ID & txtFind.Text = @ID)"
            dr = .ExecuteReader
        End With
        While dr.Read()
            found = True
            txtFirst1.Text = dr("Pfirst").ToString
            txtMid1.Text = dr("Pmiddle").ToString
            txtLast1.Text = dr("Plast").ToString
            txtAdd1.Text = dr("Paddress").ToString
            txtPhone1.Text = dr("Pphone").ToString
            txtContact1.Text = dr("Pcontact").ToString

        End While
        cn.Close()
        Exit Sub
        If found = False Then MsgBox("Patient ID not found!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        dr.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You would have a clear error message telling you what is wrong if you werent swallowing the exception.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the attempt to pass the value of `txtFind.Text` into the command.

You want to use [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
With cm
    .Connection = cn
    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblInfo WHERE ID = ?"
    .Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.[Type]).Value = txtFind.Text
    dr = .ExecuteReader
End With
```

> Note that I have used `OleDbType.[Type]`. You will want to replace this with the data type you have specified for column `ID`.

It also looks like you have missed opening the connection before calling `ExecuteReader()`:

```
cn.Open()
```

I would consider implementing [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement):

> Sometimes your code requires an unmanaged resource, such as a file handle, a COM wrapper, or a SQL connection. A Using block guarantees the disposal of one or more such resources when your code is finished with them. This makes them available for other code to use.

Here is some sample code:

```
Using con As New OleDbConnection(connectionString),
      cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblInfo WHERE ID = ?", con)

    con.Open()

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.[Type]).Value = txtFind.Text
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    ...

End Using
```